# Updating DB without going outside the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i'm trying to figure out how to trigger update upon submitting a form without actually going outside the page. i know it's possible with javascript and i've been trying to figure out how.

right now the form is build from 2 parts, the Reg.php and Update.php

Reg.php is:

```
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Title:    </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="title"><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Content</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="desc"></textarea></br>
            <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="desc" name="desc">-->
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Push</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="push" name="push"><br/>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

and update.php is:

```
<?php
    require 'connection.php';
    $sql="INSERT INTO `newsUpdate` (`title` ,`desc` ,`pushContent`) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[desc]','$_POST[push]')";
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
?>
```

so (naturally), i get the "1 record added" notification on the new page (update.php) after i the form sends the details on, but instead - i would like everything to be done on "Reg.php" include the status report (error / 1 record added)

i've tried creating a basic JS script and trigger it onClick for the button

```
function loadXMLDoc()
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","update.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

but it was a real shot in the dark - it didn't work.

can anyone point me in the right direction ? (other then reading the manual).

Comment: Wow you have to support ie5/6. Sucks to be you :-)

Comment: i don't actually have to support ie5/6 it's just a fallback that was set in the sample so i've left it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there; you just need to signify *what*  data you want sent in the XHR request (by passing a string to the `send()` method.

```
function createPostString(form) {
    var str = '';

    for (var i=0;i<form.elements.length;i++) {
        var curr = form.elements[i];

        str += encodeURIComponent(curr.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(curr.value) + '&';
    }

    return str;
}
```

Then change your `xmlhttp.send()` to `xmlhttp.send(createPostString(document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]));` (or however you want to select your form).

You haven't included your click handler in your code, but make sure you end the handler with `return false;` to stop the page submitting via traditional HTTP POST.

You can also add a complete handler to do something once the AJAX request has completed;

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        // do something with this.responseText.
    } 
};
```

---

As you've tagged your question with [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), if you want to go down that route you can use;

```
$('button[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.post("update.php", $('form').serialize()).done(function (data) {
        // Do something when the request has completed...
    });
});
```

Comment: and how do i trigger it ? or is it done automatically as long as i src jquery ?

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein: If you're talking about the jQuery script, the code I've demo'd adds a click handler via [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) to the submit `<button />`

Comment: i might be doing something wrong, i've changed it to `<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" onclick="on()">Send</button>` but it still send me to update.php upon click. the script itself was placed between <script></script> on top

Comment: @AmitSonnenschein: Like I said, the demo adds the click handler automatically. You don't have to add `on()` like you've done. See http://jsbin.com/OzeriQE/1/edit (it won't work there, because the AJAX endpoint doesn't exist, but the code is fine). Make sure you're adding jQuery to your page, and you've wrapped the jQuery in a `$(document).ready()` block; both of which are shown in the demo I've just linked to.

Comment: *facepalm* yes.. now i see it.